# CSS3DObject Render Issues with GSAP

Tags: animation, three.js, gsap

I have a main div which is placed on a plane geometry using CSS3DObject… I have two sub DIVs like section1 and section2 inside that main div that are placed one behind another… I have this simple GSAP animation where section1 hides with an opacity and section2 shows up… Everything is working great but the only problem is that while animating everything gets blurred until the animation completes.

Reference Video:
https://streamable.com/mzq71i

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people like me who may face the same problem in future…

I’ve found the solution. Just write `force3D:false` this in your gsap animation

Like this:

```
gsap.to(".class", {opacity: 1, duration: 2, force3D:false})
```

Cheers!